# How to write and use config files in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Hi,

In Zend Framwork 1, I used to have an `application\configs\appsettings.xml`, where I used to store params and values like hostnames for Rest API URLs, debug settings and other application specific settings for dev, test and prod environments. This registry was available to me across all controllers and models and was created in index.php

```
   $applicationEnvironment = 'development';
   $config = new Zend_Config_Xml( APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/appsettings.xml',
                                  $applicationEnvironment, true );
    Zend_Registry::set( 'config', $config );
```

How do I achieve similar thing in Zend Framework 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `Registry` in ZF2 because it is kind of an anti pattern. It's just a fancy substitution for global variables, which can cause all sort of unwanted side effects in your application.

In ZF2 you have the serviceManager and this allow to cleanly inject all your dependencies into your controllers/models/services. All config files in the config/autoload directory are automaticaly merged into one single array by ZF2 and you can retrieve this from the service manager using `$serviceLocator->get('Config')`. Whenever you need to use configuration in your controller just create a serviceFactory and inject the config.

```
class FooController
{
    protected $config;

    public __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public barAction()
    {
        //use $this->config
    }
}

class Module
{
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'fooController' => function(ControllerManager $cm) 
                {
                    $sm   = $cm->getServiceLocator();
                    $config = $sm->get('Config');
                    $controller = new FooController($config);
                    return $controller;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

For sake of simplicity the factory above is defined as a closure, but I'd suggest to create a seperate factory class. There are many resources which explain how to do that.

In this example we are injecting the complete configuration, but depending on your use case it will generally be better to only inject the config keys you need.

Alternatively you can wrap certain config values into a dedicated config object with explicit getters and setters and inject this into your controller. `Zend\StdLib\AbstractOptions` can help you.

Comment: The factory that you showed seems to apply for "fooController" only. But I see that many modules and controllers in my app, might need to use the settings in the config array. Is there a way to generalize this?

Comment: You can implement the interface `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in your controller, which will trigger the servicemanager to automatically inject the servicelocator on instanciation (Called initializers). You can even write your own initializer to inject the config. See [this blog post](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/injecting-configuration-into-a-zf2-controller/). I tend to avoid initializers and try to be explicit, because they do a lot of magic behind the scenes and make debugging more difficult.

Comment: I think a controller plugin would be ideal for this (if the need is just within the controllers). Create one, inject the config and have a nice API to access the config data; much like the current [params plugin](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params)

Comment: @AlexP. Controller plugin is also a nice idea. It only makes your code a bit more difficult to test.

Comment: @BramGerritsen. Thank you for that link. I was able to follow through and now able to get the configuration i need in a controller that implements the configawareinterface. However, what do I need to do if I need the config keys in the model file?

Comment: Add the same definition for initializer to the `getServiceConfig` method and remove the line saying `$locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();`

Comment: hmm.. I implemented that and made my model extend ConfigAwareInterface as well, but the config property seems to be empty.

Comment: Btw you must make sure your models are also created by the servicemanager for the above to work. Define them as invokables / factories in your servicemanager.

Comment: Wow.. So much roundabout of things to achieve a very simple thing.. hmm..why so complicated? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47364/discussion-between-jake-and-bram-gerritsen)

Comment: It can seem a bit overwhelming at first, but once you get a hold of it things will become easy and second nature. It allows for really clean application architecture and make things very flexible and extensible. I suggest you to read up more about the servicemanager as it is the most important component of zf2.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to work with config files and you dont have access to the Service Manager or you wish to write content to it, you can use Zend\Config

To read from, you can do something like:

```
$config = new Config(include 'config/autoload/my_amazing_config.global.php');
$details = $config->get('array_key')->get(sub_key)->toArray();
```

To write to, you can do:

```
// Create the config object
$config = new Zend\Config\Config(array(), true);
$config->production = array();

$config->production->webhost = 'www.example.com';
$config->production->database = array();
$config->production->database->params = array();
$config->production->database->params->host = 'localhost';
$config->production->database->params->username = 'production';
$config->production->database->params->password = 'secret';
$config->production->database->params->dbname = 'dbproduction';

$writer = new Zend\Config\Writer\Xml();
echo $writer->toString($config);
```

The class support ini, xml, phpArray, json, yaml

You can read more at:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.config.introduction.html

Comment: Awesome. Thank you ! I was able to do this in Model files.

Comment: which file its gonna write to? to my_amazing_config.global.php?